# JSON contains a list, and I want to splice the values of a field in the list

Tags: python, json

I want to extract the "words" field from "td" and display it in a line. How to use Python to achieve this effect? Thank.

```
td = {'words_result': [{'words': 'a/b/c'},
                      {'words': '/c/b/a'},
                      {'words': '/1/2/3'},
                      {'words': '/3/2/1'}]}

Expectant_effect ='a/b/c/c/b/a/1/2/3/3/2/1'
```

Comment: `print (''.join(y for x in td['words_result'] for y in x.values()))`

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that code:

```
res = []
words_result = td.get('words_result')
for words_dict in words_result:
    res.append(words_dict.get('words'))
result = ''.join(res)

print(Expectant_effect == result)
```

Comment: Thank you Sima. It can be compiled and passed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From code it seems it's a dictionary rather than a JSON string. So I have two ways here

If it's just a dictionary - *easy peasy*

```
for i in td['words_list']:
    print(i, end='')
```

If it's actually a JSON string - *just one extra import*

```
import json

jsonString = '{"words_result": [{"words": "a/b/b"}, {"words": "/d/b/a"}, {"words": "1/2/3"}, {"words": "/3/2/1"}]}'
dictString = json.loads(jsonString)

# now same as above
for i in dictString ['words_list']:
    print(i, end='')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can run, Have a nice afternoon,hah hah.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't forget to upvote and accept answers that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
td = {'words_result': [{'words': 'a/b/c'},
                      {'words': '/c/b/a'},
                      {'words': '/1/2/3'},
                      {'words': '/3/2/1'}]}
line = '' 
for item in td['words_result']: 
            line+= item['words']                  
#Get YOUR RESULT
print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, compiled through . 